# PDFToPrinter for Windows opens GUI on some machines

Tags: windows, pdf, printing, php

[PDFToPrinter](http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/pdftoprinter.html) is an executable for Windows which lets you print a PDF file to a printer, especially to a shared network printer using the `\\host\printer` syntax.

I'm using it to print PDFs from within a PHP script without user interaction. On our development machine - a Windows 10 Pro system - it works as expected and prints just fine. On our clients machine - also a Windows 10 Pro system - it will open the bundled PDF-XChange Viewer GUI with no PDF file loaded.

I already contacted the author and his only guess was that maybe some settings got messed up and he asked me to remove the `%TEMP%\PDFPrinterTmp`-Folder and retry it, but it didn't change the behaviour after doing that.

Any ideas why it behaves different on two identical OS-Versions and what to try to stop it from opening the GUI? Or are there viable alternatives for printing PDF files without interaction and from a PHP script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always: if all conditions are the same on the software side of things, the culprit has to be found on the hardware side.

In our case, the USB port of the USB hub that the printer was connected to was malfunctioning. Using another port next to it "fixed" the problem and PDFToPrinter behaves now as expected.

The proper way to debug this issue would be to exclude software issues and then to replace all hardware components like USB cable, optionally a USB hub if used and last but not least the printer itself.